# Adding nodes to programmatically created JTrees in Java

Tags: java, jtree

I'm creating this app that creates tabs and JTrees on button click events. The problem is when I try to add ne node to a JTree it doesn't refresh the JTree ( or it doesn't add the node to it ... I don't really know).

This is the functions that creates the tabs and trees:

```
jTabbedPane1.add(st,jSplitpane10);
int count = jTabbedPane1.getTabCount();
jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(count-1);

DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("All Notebooks");
DefaultMutableTreeNode notebook1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Notebook 1");
root.add(notebook1);

// Create tree
JTree tree = new JTree(root);
//Create Scroll Pane for the tree
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(tree);

Global.trees.add(tree);
```

And this is the code that is supposed to add new node "Green" to a tree in the selected tab:

```
int i = jTabbedPane1.getSelectedIndex();
DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel)Global.trees.get(i).getModel();

// Find node to which new node is to be added
int startRow = 0;
String prefix = "J";
TreePath path = Global.trees.get(i).getNextMatch(prefix, startRow, Position.Bias.Forward);
MutableTreeNode node = (MutableTreeNode)path.getLastPathComponent();

// Create new node
MutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("green");

// Insert new node as last child of node
model.insertNodeInto(newNode, node, node.getChildCount());
model.reload(newNode);
```

Here's also the declaration of the global list of JTrees:

```
public class Global {
    public java.util.List<JTree> trees = new ArrayList<JTree>();
}Global Global;
```

Any ideas why new nodes aren't showing in the trees???

Comment: @DuncanJones It says: "method fireTreeNodesInserted in class DefaultTreeModel cannot be applied to given types"

Comment: if you place a break point at model.reload(newNode); you should be able to inspect your model and see if the node has been added properly to the model and where you expect it to be. That would at least answer the " or it doesn't add the node to it ... I don't really know)" part of the question :)

Comment: Can you produce a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that people can play with? (I deleted my previous comment after becoming thoroughly confused by the myriad of node notification methods in `DefaultTreeModel`!

Comment: @DuncanJones Sure! Can I somehow send you the java file? It's really SSCCE cause I'm just starting.

Comment: @Igor, no. Please condense to the smallest possible example of your issue and post it here for everyone to see.

Comment: I have told to debug it with a dump the model to the console, but if want a ready copy-paste code, that is not help it is a work...

Answer (score 1):

JTree and JTable are the most complex Swing components.

I think is reloaded, but not expanded. 
The JTree root node has many settings: how handler or not show root node or not and so on.

I am using a debug console listing where I dump the model data as text ( override the toString() in nodes too) and I can see easily,, what is there, but if you have just a few nodes not needed, it is enough with the Netbeans's debugger.

Also try to expand all rows in tree to have it visible.

Your code is good:

```
// Create new node
MutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("green");

// Insert new node as last child of node
model.insertNodeInto(newNode, node, node.getChildCount());
model.reload(newNode);
```

but probably it is not visible, you need to expand, how to do it, that is another question

Comment: This doesn't really appear to be an answer.

Comment: @matheszabi This is not helping Mathe

Comment: If you want to see only a code which you copy-paste, than I wil not write now. I told need to expand the tree nodes after the node added. Just do a google search how to expand it, if you are to lazy to make a string representation of your model  http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t61157.html

Comment: @matheszabi Ok, I now retract my earlier comment, I think we are both thinking the same thing now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to add JTree programmatically:

Source:http://sickprogrammersarea.blogspot.in/2014/03/add-jtree-programmatically-in-java-swing.html

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
public class MyTree extends JApplet
{
  JTree t;
  JLabel l1;
  String lang[]={"C","C++","JAVA","PYTHON","AJAX","PHP"};
  public void init()
  {
    try
    {
     SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
       public void run()
       {
          makeGUI();
       }
    });
    } catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("Sorry some error occured "+e);
    }
}
private void makeGUI()
{
   DefaultMutableTreeNode top=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Language");
   DefaultMutableTreeNode a=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Programming");
   top.add(a);
   DefaultMutableTreeNode a1=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("C");
   a.add(a1);
   DefaultMutableTreeNode a2=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Java");
   a.add(a2);
   DefaultMutableTreeNode b=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Web Based");
   top.add(b);
   DefaultMutableTreeNode b1=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("PHP");
   b.add(b1);
   DefaultMutableTreeNode b2=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("JSP");
   b.add(b2);
   t=new JTree(top);
   JScrollPane scr=new JScrollPane(t);
   add(scr);
   setLayout(new  FlowLayout());
   l1=new JLabel("Choose a language");
   add(l1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   t.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener () {
    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent ae) { 
      l1.setText(ae.getPath()+" is selected");
    }
  });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I produced a small example application to test your issue. I found that the node was being added correctly, but not expanding. Also, the call to `model.reload` seems unnecessary.

I added a call to `expandPath` on the tree to cause the display to show the new node. You may need to double check this doesn't expand too much of the tree:

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

  private JTree tree;

  public Example() {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("All Notebooks");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode notebook1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Notebook 1");
    root.add(notebook1);

    tree = new JTree(root);
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(tree);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(new JButton("Go") {
    {
      addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          Example.this.addNode();
        }
      });
    }}, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
  }


  private void addNode() {
    DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();

    // Find node to which new node is to be added
    int startRow = 0;
    String prefix = "N";
    TreePath path = tree.getNextMatch(prefix, startRow,
        Position.Bias.Forward);
    MutableTreeNode node = (MutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();

    // Create new node
    MutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("green");

    // Insert new node as last child of node
    model.insertNodeInto(newNode, node, node.getChildCount());
    tree.expandPath(path);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {    
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {      
      @Override
      public void run() {
        new Example().setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Duncun, but I'm creating multiple tabs and trees that I add to a List<JTree>. So this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not going to spoon feed you an exact answer. But I'm sure you can derive the correct way to do this for your application from this example?

Comment: I see that you have declared a global JTree variable, but I'm creating mine in a local button click funtion and adding then in a global List. I can't think of any other way to do it right now. Can you?

Comment: I think between @matheszabi and I, we've given you enough to solve your original issue. Your problem is apparently related to expansion of tree nodes. If you have other programming issues, prepare a SSCCE and post a new question (after suitable research and effort on your own part).

Comment: OK your example works fine. But what if there was one more button that should create a new tab, a tree and a 'Go' button. The 'Go' button adds node to the tree in it's tab. How would you implement that?